# Class name convention in java

Tags: java, naming-conventions, uppercase, classname

What is the naming convention of classes in java, for example should all classes be in upper case like MYCLASS.java ?

as some classes like  **com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.generic. ANEWARRAY**. can be found in Sun's library as well

Note: I have read all naming convention from [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) but I could not find anything which says we should name a class with All Uppercase.

Comment: Everybody just uses camel-case for class names, so I would probably just stick with that.

Comment: In some programming languages Uppercase words are used for constants. It could be confusing.

Comment: The "standard" convention: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367

Comment: The only case I can imagine (according to convention) that this is an abbreviation:

ANiceEggWasAtRoughRoundArrayYeti

Comment: *"Like we have some classes in com.sun.."*  Remove them immediately.  Do not put classes in the `com.sun` package (unless you are Sun, or bought the company).

Comment: I think he is referring to [Class ANEWARRAY](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/apidocs/org/apache/bcel/generic/ANEWARRAY.html) although the `com.sun` should not be part of the package name.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I have not put this class in com.sun.... its already a part of Sun's library

Comment: @supericy I know we use camel-case but I just wanted to know is there any naming convention which suggests us to use all Uppercase

Comment: @maba you are right I am referring to class ANEWARRAY and com.sun is not part of my package structure some one had edited my post and made it confusing

Comment: @ankit "I could not find anything which says we should name a class with All Uppercase." Why do you think there would be? Thats not the convention

Comment: It's pascal case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After browsing through many links I came to know there is no java convention which suggests us to name a class in all uppercases. However we do so there will not be any error.

One appropriate reason is mentioned by [CloudyMarble](https://stackoverflow.com/users/395659/cloudymarble) that we can use this convention if the abbreviation is more famous like HTML.

Also I would like to add some info about ANEWARRAY, this class comes under Apache license [Source](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~joehw/jdk8/7160496/src/webrev/src/com/sun/org/apache/bcel/internal/generic/ANEWARRAY.java.html) and Create new array of references.

Answer (score 16):

Class Names should be in CamelCase. Try to use nouns because a class is normally representing something in the real world.

The [Documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#15411) states the following:

> Class names should be nouns, in mixed case with the first letter of
>   each internal word capitalized. Try to keep your class names simple
>   and descriptive. Use whole words-avoid acronyms and abbreviations
>   (unless the abbreviation is much more widely used than the long form,
>   such as URL or HTML).

Comment: What you described is actually Pascal casing. Camel casing has the first letter lower case.

Comment: Any idea if there's a more modern document specifying these conventions? The document you've linked to is marked as unsupported and last edited in 1999.

Answer (score 4):

Java has a very well described naming / coding convention.

You can look it up here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html

Technically it doesn't matter how you name you classes as long as public classes are in a .java-source file with the same name as the class.

Answer (score 1):

The quoted class com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.generic.ANEWARRAY looks to be from the deep innerworking of Java (internal.generic), i.e. not for developer use. As such its really outside of the naming convention. I can only speculate as to why its all in capitals, perhaps to emphasise this point that it shouldn't be used.

Comment: sorry to say but, you had made my question confusing I have already read all the naming conventions in java and I could not find anything telling class name should be all Uppercase, thats why I asked this question.

Comment: @ankit Thats because classes *shouldn't* be all in uppercase

Comment: com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.generic. ANEWARRAY this is a class provided by sun and it has name in all uppercase.

Comment: @ankit Ahhh, the way you originally wrote your question it seemed (not just to me) like you had created that class yourself

Comment: I have corrected it now, and sorry for the misleading question but your edit added oil to fire ;). I think both of us have learnt something isnt it ?

Comment: @ankit Have updated answer, although its more of a "Don't worry about it" answer than anything else

Answer (score 0):

Usually the best practise is to use Upper CamelCase.anyway there will be no compilation issues with other conventions.see more details about [conventions](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm)