# how to call method that contains array

Tags: java

Complete beginner here. I am trying to call a method from a class to run in the main class. But I cannot seem to figure out why it is not work. Here is how I am calling the class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
      findMP3Tracks FT = new findMP3Tracks();
      FT.findMP3();
```

This is the class method i want to call

```
public static List<String> findMP3(String p)
{
    List<String> foundMP3Tracks = new ArrayList<>();

    try (DirectoryStream<Path> folderContents = Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get(p))) 
    { 
        //Look for 
        for (Path folderItem: folderContents){ 
 if(Files.isDirectory(folderItem, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS)) {
                foundMP3Tracks.addAll(findMP3(folderItem.toString()));
            }
            else if(isValidMP3(folderItem.toString())) {
                foundMP3Tracks.add(folderItem.toString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should post what error you get.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `findMP3(String)` is a method inside the class `findMP3Tracks` (I would recommend you to follow [Java conventions for class names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16537620/class-name-convention-in-java)), you may call it in the main as:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
      ...
      List<String> result = findMP3Tracks.findMP3("Name of MP3");
}
```

You may use the name of the class `findMP3Tracks` to invoke the method `findMP3`, because it is declared as **static**. So it's not necessary to create an instance to call it. (Of course you may want to create instances of that class for other operations)

Also, since `findMP3` is returning a `List<String>`, you may want to store it in a variable (In the example `result`)

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need instances to call a static method, so this line

```
findMP3Tracks FT = new findMP3Tracks();
```

is useless, you can remove it.

Use (for example)

```
findMP3Tracks.findMP3("Some MP3 name");
```

Also you need to get the returned value, so it should be:

```
final List<String> mp3List = findMP3Tracks.findMP3("Some MP3 name");
```

PS: in Java by convention class names start with uppercase, I suggest you change `findMP3Tracks` class name to `FindMP3Tracks`

Answer (score 0):

You've declared the method as

```
public static List<String> findMP3(String p)
```

which means (among other things) that when you call it, you're going to pass in a `String` argument.  But you wrote

```
FT.findMP3();
```

where you're not passing in any argument at all.  Something like

```
FT.findMP3("Hello");
```

would compile; or if you had a `String` variable whose value was the name of the MP3 that you wanted to search for, you could use that too.  But the call to any method MUST match the declaration of that method.

Answer (score -1):

The method `findMP3` is declared as static. Static variables and methods are members of the class.

You can invoke it directly using the classname. So, it should be `findMP3Tracks.findMP3()`

Also, a word about the static method. If you do know that the behaviour of the method isnt different for different instances, then you might/can declare it as static. Although, it is a design decision that you would make. If it does behave differently based on the passed in parameter, it is better off to have a method which isnt static.

Comment: Thank you guys for your response. I will try the suggestion ASAP.