# How to limit the MySQL Query with Ebean in Play Framework

Tags: mysql, playframework, ebean

Heys guys,
i have a Problem using Play Framework.
I am trying to display a large amount of Data (from this Database). When i am using the "find.all()" the Play Framework Server crashes, since it takes to much memory.

I got a DB Model named:

```
@Entity
public class dblp_pub_new extends Model {
[...]
    public dblp_pub_new() {}

    public static List<dblp_pub_new> all() {
        return find.all();
    }

    public String getDoi() {
        return doi;
    }

    public void setMdate() {
        this.mdate = new Date();
    }

    public static Finder<String,dblp_pub_new> find = new Finder<String, dblp_pub_new>(String.class, dblp_pub_new.class);

}
```

My rendering function is, which is contained in Application.java:

```
public static Result dois(){
    return ok(views.html.index.render(dblp_pub_new.all(), DoiForm));
}
```

I am trying to limit the all() Query to 50 (best would be per page). But i cant seem to figure it out. I think i need a List returned to display it on the webpage. But I can't get it to work.
I would be really relieved if one of you guys (and girls) could help me figuring out this problem. 
I've tried it with "fetch" and "setMaxRows()" but I only get errors i can't seem to solve.
If there is something unclear, please just ask and i will try to provide as much information as i can.
Thank you.

Comment: have you tried using query.setFirstRow((value));?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ebean has a helper for making pagination of data easier. It's called a [`PagingList`](http://www.avaje.org/ebean/introquery_paginglist.html) there.  Play's [`Finder` helper class](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/java/index.html) for Ebeans [allows you to get such a `PagingList` for your query](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/java/play/db/ebean/Model.Finder.html#findPagingList(int)).

Say you want to display 50 items per page, and want to retrieve the items for the first page. Then you'd write something like this

```
public static List<dblp_pub_new> getpageItems(int page) {
    int pageSize = 50;
    return find.findPagingList(pageSize).getPage(page).getList();
}
```

Also, please note that your class name `dblp_pub_new` is highly unusual. Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16537620/class-name-convention-in-java) for more information.

Comment: Thank you very much. That completely solves the issue. So effectiv and yet so easy. I don't know how i could not see that solution. I hope I get everything else to work ;)

Comment: As of July 2017, there's no findPagingList method in Finder, closest being findPagedList on which you can't set page size

Answer (score 13):

Using `setMaxRows()` should work. Try this:

```
dblp_pub_new.find.setMaxRows(50).findList()
```

By the way, you should name your class according to the Java convention : `DblpPubNew`. It will make your code easier to read.

Comment: I have not tried this yet, but will keep an eye on it. I could not name my class according to the Java convention, since this database is already up and working (not under my "lead") and I am just trying to get access to it. But anyway, thanks for your help too!

Comment: `setMaxRows` doesn't work for `findPagingList`. Why? Are the pages lazy loaded? I don't think so..!?

Answer (score 0):

in addition to **Carsten's** answer I only mention that [Page](http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/com/avaje/ebean/Page.html) itself contains several useful methods which help i.e. building pagination menu in the view, so it's easier to use whole Page object:

```
public static com.avaje.ebean.Page<dblp_pub_new> getPage(int pageSize, int page) {
    return find.findPagingList(pageSize).getPage(page);
}
```

and then you can use it in the view like:

```
<ul>
  @for(item <- myPage.getList){
    <li>@item.name</li>
  }
</ul>

<b>Total page count is: @myPage.getTotalPageCount()</b>
```

Answer (score 0):

The currently accepted answer suggesting `findPagingList` is not valid anymore. See https://github.com/ebean-orm/ebean/issues/96

Now using `setMaxRows()` should work with any `Query` but you have to use `findPagedList`  on that (vs. `findPagingList`). Something like this:

```
List<dblp_pub_new> list = dblp_pub_new.find.query()
   .where().eq("some_column", some_value)
   .orderBy("some_column desc")
   .setMaxRows(50)
   .findPagedList()
   .findList()
```